# XSLT - Remove full parent node if grandchild element contains specific text

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I want to do xml to xml tranformation using XSLT 1.0. I need to remove full node from XML, if "Removeornot" value is not "1".

I already tried to create template:

```
<xsl:template match="//Node[not(Grandchild0[not(Grand3child[not(Grand4child[not(Grand5child[not(Grand6child[not(Removeornot = 1)])])])])])]"/>
```

This template works fine if xml has less levels, but I cannot adobt it to my solution. So maybe somebody can help with it.

Source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Family>
    <Node>
        <Child0>AAA</Child0>
        <Child1>BBB</Child1>
        <Child2>
            <Grandchild0>
                <Grand2child>DDD</Grand2child>
                <Grand3child>
                    <Grand4child>
                        <Grand5child>
                            <Grand6child>
                                <Removeornot>1</Removeornot>
                            </Grand6child>
                            <Grand6child1>QQQ </Grand6child1>
                        </Grand5child>
                        <Grand5child1>ZZZ </Grand5child1>
                    </Grand4child>
                </Grand3child>
                <Grand2child2>EEE</Grand2child2>
            </Grandchild0>
            <Grandchild2>FFF</Grandchild2>
            <Grandchild3>GGG</Grandchild3>
            <Grandchild4>HHH</Grandchild4>
            <Grandchild5>IIII</Grandchild5>
        </Child2>
    </Node>
    <Node>
        <Child0>AAA</Child0>
        <Child1>BBB</Child1>
        <Child2>
            <Grandchild0>
                <Grand2child>DDD</Grand2child>
                <Grand3child>
                    <Grand4child>
                        <Grand5child>
                            <Grand6child>
                                <Removeornot>YES</Removeornot>
                            </Grand6child>
                            <Grand6child1>QQQ </Grand6child1>
                        </Grand5child>
                        <Grand5child1>ZZZ </Grand5child1>
                    </Grand4child>
                </Grand3child>
                <Grand2child2>EEE</Grand2child2>
            </Grandchild0>
            <Grandchild2>FFF</Grandchild2>
            <Grandchild3>GGG</Grandchild3>
            <Grandchild4>HHH</Grandchild4>
            <Grandchild5>IIII</Grandchild5>
        </Child2>
    </Node>
    <Node>
        <Child0>AAA</Child0>
        <Child1>BBB</Child1>
        <Child2>
            <Grandchild0>
                <Grand2child>DDD</Grand2child>
                <Grand3child>
                    <Grand4child>
                        <Grand5child>
                            <Grand6child>
                                <Removeornot>NO</Removeornot>
                            </Grand6child>
                            <Grand6child1>QQQ </Grand6child1>
                        </Grand5child>
                        <Grand5child1>ZZZ </Grand5child1>
                    </Grand4child>
                </Grand3child>
                <Grand2child2>EEE</Grand2child2>
            </Grandchild0>
            <Grandchild2>FFF</Grandchild2>
            <Grandchild3>GGG</Grandchild3>
            <Grandchild4>HHH</Grandchild4>
            <Grandchild5>IIII</Grandchild5>
        </Child2>
    </Node>
</Family>
```

This XSLT just prints "Removeornot" value. Other approach to accomplish this task was to use this value as variable, but as I understand variables in XSLT is fully immutable and I cannot use them outside for-each loop. Any ideas how can I use this value to remove node if value content is wrong?

XSLT Source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="v2">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="Family/Node">
      <xsl:call-template name="tests"></xsl:call-template>
      <!-- Is it possible to get variable value here to understand if node shloud be deleted?
             <xsl:if test="$tester = 1">
             <xsl:call-template name="copyit"></xsl:call-template>
              </xsl:if> -->
       </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tests">
<!--      <xsl:for-each select="Family/Node"> -->
    <xsl:for-each select="Child2/Grandchild0">
        <xsl:for-each select="Grand3child/Grand4child">
            <xsl:for-each select="Grand5child/Grand6child">
                <xsl:value-of select="Removeornot"></xsl:value-of>
                    <!--  <xsl:variable name="tester" select="Removeornot" ></xsl:variable>-->
                 </xsl:for-each>
             </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:for-each>
 <!--      </xsl:for-each> -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="copyit">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
     </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Family>
    <Node>
        <Child0>AAA</Child0>
        <Child1>BBB</Child1>
        <Child2>
            <Grandchild0>
                <Grand2child>DDD</Grand2child>
                <Grand3child>
                    <Grand4child>
                        <Grand5child>
                            <Grand6child>
                                <Removeornot>1</Removeornot>
                            </Grand6child>
                            <Grand6child1>QQQ </Grand6child1>
                        </Grand5child>
                        <Grand5child1>ZZZ </Grand5child1>
                    </Grand4child>
                </Grand3child>
                <Grand2child2>EEE</Grand2child2>
            </Grandchild0>
            <Grandchild2>FFF</Grandchild2>
            <Grandchild3>GGG</Grandchild3>
            <Grandchild4>HHH</Grandchild4>
            <Grandchild5>IIII</Grandchild5>
        </Child2>
    </Node>
</Family>
```

I'm new too XSLT, every help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to remove full node from XML, if "Removeornot" value is not "1".

That would be

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Node[not(.//Removeornot = 1)]" />
</xsl:transform>
```

1. The identity template copies every node unless a more specific template matches.
2. The other template for `Node[not(.//Removeornot = 1)]` is more specific - and it outputs nothing for any nodes that match here, which in effect removes those nodes from the input.

Comment: Thank you! It's works with this example, however how to match specific //Removeornot? For example: If Child1/../Removeornot also have sutch element?

Comment: Your comment already contains the answer to that. Give it five minutes, it will come to you.

Comment: @Artūrs So, did you figure it out?

Comment: Yes, thanks! There was namespaces, that confused me, but now it's clear :) One more thing about namespaces. Source file had one "xmlns" in different places, but after transformation only first "xmlns" value left. Is there any way to get identical copy?

Comment: @ArtūrsLelītis Good to hear! :) As for your question: Identical XML files do not necessarily look alike when you compare their serialized form. Two XML documents are identical when and only when their DOMs are identical. Therefore it's completely immaterial where `xmlns` appears in the serialized file, different serializers simply have different output.